# Is possible (and how to) cache an html5 <video> source?

Tags: caching, html, video

I know this question is rather strange ,so let me explain. I got an html5  application, an avatar that answers questions. However, while not busy, i want my avatar to display a waiting animation. Got my video, and it works just fine, but it is a 2 secs video that i want to access without asking the server every time i have to play it, its just too much traffic. What i want is to download it once, and then be able to play it every time i need. Is there anyway to cache it? Other solutions are wellcomed too ^^.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that works, but you can try using cache manifest. Here is info on how to use it: http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Application-Caching/

Briefly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html manifest="manifest.cache"> 
....
```

manifest.cache

```
#What to cache for reuse
CACHE MANIFEST 
index.html 
stylesheet.css 
images/masthead.png 
scripts/misc.js 

#What to cache in case network goes down (if network is up it will still try to load it from net)
NETWORK: 
search.php 
login.php 
/api 

#What to show when resource is not cached and no way to load it
FALLBACK: 
images/dynamic.php static_image.png
```